# how to remove the start of a link and add a forward slash in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, urllib

I have some weblinks that I have scraped off a website, the problem is the links are not totally correct, as in they don't automatically download the data unless I make **two** changes:

**1)** I get rid of the `VM300:1` at the start

**2)** I put a `/` after the `.au`

Is there a way to do this automatically? I have about a thousand links so its not preferable to be doing this manually.

Below is an example of my url's

```
urls = [
    "VM300:1 https://www.powerwater.com.au__data/assets/excel_doc/0011/172775/Market_Information_System_Control_daily_trading_day_190130.xlsx",
    "VM300:1 https://www.powerwater.com.au__data/assets/excel_doc/0004/172732/Market_Information_System_Control_daily_trading_day_190129.xlsx",
    "VM300:1 https://www.powerwater.com.au__data/assets/excel_doc/0010/172675/Market_Information_System_Control_daily_trading_day_190128.xlsx",
    "VM300:1 https://www.powerwater.com.au__data/assets/excel_doc/0009/172674/Market_Information_System_Control_daily_trading_day_190127.xlsx",
    "VM300:1 https://www.powerwater.com.au__data/assets/excel_doc/0008/172673/Market_Information_System_Control_daily_trading_day_190126.xlsx",
    "VM300:1 https://www.powerwater.com.au__data/assets/excel_doc/0007/172672/Market_Information_System_Control_daily_trading_day_190125.xlsx",
    "VM300:1 https://www.powerwater.com.au__data/assets/excel_doc/0011/172595/Market_Information_System_Control_daily_trading_day_190124.xlsx"
]
```

EDIT1

```
from pathlib import Path

import requests

urls = [
    "VM300:1 https://www.powerwater.com.au__data/assets/excel_doc/0011/172775/Market_Information_System_Control_daily_trading_day_190130.xlsx",
    "VM300:1 https://www.powerwater.com.au__data/assets/excel_doc/0004/172732/Market_Information_System_Control_daily_trading_day_190129.xlsx",
    "VM300:1 https://www.powerwater.com.au__data/assets/excel_doc/0010/172675/Market_Information_System_Control_daily_trading_day_190128.xlsx",
    "VM300:1 https://www.powerwater.com.au__data/assets/excel_doc/0009/172674/Market_Information_System_Control_daily_trading_day_190127.xlsx",
    "VM300:1 https://www.powerwater.com.au__data/assets/excel_doc/0008/172673/Market_Information_System_Control_daily_trading_day_190126.xlsx",
    "VM300:1 https://www.powerwater.com.au__data/assets/excel_doc/0007/172672/Market_Information_System_Control_daily_trading_day_190125.xlsx",
    "VM300:1 https://www.powerwater.com.au__data/assets/excel_doc/0011/172595/Market_Information_System_Control_daily_trading_day_190124.xlsx"
]

urls = [x.replace('VM300:1 ','').replace('.au__', '.au/__') for x in urls]


for url in urls:
    r = requests.get(urls)
    with open(Path(urls).name, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(r.content)
```

ERROR:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/george/Desktop/NT/stack NT.py", line 19, in <module>
    r = requests.get(urls)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 640, in send
    adapter = self.get_adapter(url=request.url)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 731, in get_adapter
    raise InvalidSchema("No connection adapters were found for '%s'" % url)
InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for '['https://www.powerwater.com.au/__data/assets/excel_doc/0011/172775/Market_Information_System_Control_daily_trading_day_190130.xlsx', 'https://www.powerwater.com.au/__data/assets/excel_doc/0004/172732/Market_Information_System_Control_daily_trading_day_190129.xlsx', 'https://www.powerwater.com.au/__data/assets/excel_doc/0010/172675/Market_Information_System_Control_daily_trading_day_190128.xlsx', 'https://www.powerwater.com.au/__data/assets/excel_doc/0009/172674/Market_Information_System_Control_daily_trading_day_190127.xlsx', 'https://www.powerwater.com.au/__data/assets/excel_doc/0008/172673/Market_Information_System_Control_daily_trading_day_190126.xlsx', 'https://www.powerwater.com.au/__data/assets/excel_doc/0007/172672/Market_Information_System_Control_daily_trading_day_190125.xlsx', 'https://www.powerwater.com.au/__data/assets/excel_doc/0011/172595/Market_Information_System_Control_daily_trading_day_190124.xlsx']'
```

Thank you

Comment: What about this, `[url.split()[-1].replace('__','/') for url in urls]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use list comprehension with `split` and `replace`:

```
urls = [x.split()[1].replace('.au__', '.au/__') for x in urls]
```

Another idea with double `replace`:

```
urls = [x.replace('VM300:1 ','').replace('.au__', '.au/__') for x in urls]
```

Comment: or maybe `urls = [x.split()[1].replace('.au__', '.au/') for x in urls]`, depending on what they need

Comment: @Shinratensei - Just tested output links and file was downloded correctly, so need `__`

Comment: @Shinratensei - No, thank you. It was my first idea too, but links was wrong, returned error page `(Page not found)`.

Comment: Any idea why I get an error when running my code? I edited my post to show this

Comment: @newtoR - there is typo `r = requests.get(urls)` to `r = requests.get(url)` (removed last `s`)

Comment: @newtoR - and also `(Path(url)`

Comment: if you are still there I have one question that maybe I could ask you?

Comment: @newtoR - sure, come on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187656/discussion-between-newtor-and-jezrael).